# How to silently install the Microsoft Monitoring Agent

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I am trying to install an `.exe` application (Win32 Cabinet Self-Extractor) *silently* from command line using this PowerShell command:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MMASetup-i386.exe" -ArgumentList "/s" -wait
```

But everytime I get a pops up window with this error:

> command line option syntax error. Type command /? for help.

What am I doing wrong? I am on Windows Server 2012R2 and using PowerShell-4.

Comment: Do you have a global policy which prevents running the executable from the temp directory?  The other thing I would try is using single-quotes instead of double-quotes, since you don't have any variable expansion.

Comment: So when you run `mmasetup-i386.exe /s` from a command line it works?  From what you've written it appears that the mmasetup-i386 is reporting an invalid option.  What is the ouput of `mmasetup-i386 /?`

Comment: @DavidPaige: No don't have any that kind of policy, and using single-quotes is also giving same error.

Comment: @TonyHinkle: I get this `Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '/?'.`

Comment: Start a normal DOS command prompt and run `mmasetup-386.exe /?` and it will hopefully show the valid parameters.

Comment: Is this the Microsoft Monitoring Agent?

Comment: @TonyHinkle: Yes!

Comment: This is not really a Powershell question, it is about how to silently install the Microsoft Monitoring Agent.  You should rewrite the question accordingly if you need help as there may be someone that knows how to do this, but the title won't catch their attention.

Comment: @TonyHinkle: Thanks to pointing this. Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MMASetup-i386 uses the /Q for quiet install, not /s.

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MMASetup-i386.exe" -ArgumentList "/Q" -wait`

You can often find the valid arguments for an .exe by running it with the /? argument, such as:

`MMASetup-i386.exe /?`

However, that is not always the case and sometimes you may need to consult the documentation or search the developer's website or the Internet in general for it.

Comment: Powershell will never give you a popup like you are seeing.  That is the clue that the message is coming from the .exe that is being started, not from Powershell.

Comment: I run above command and get this error: `Error creating process << none>>. Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Can you tell me or edit in your answer how do we know which `executable` has which `flag`?

Comment: Hmmmm.  Are you sure you got the path to the .Exe correct?   The only thing you needed to change from the original command was /s to /Q

Comment: Yes, I changed only `/s` to `/Q` and I am sure path is correct.

Comment: OK--I ran the same thing, and once again it is not a Powershell error.  That is an error from Microsoft Monitoring Agent Installer.  You need to do some searching for that error--it has absolutely nothing to do with Powershell.

Comment: See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230736.aspx I think there are a lot of parameters that are need for MOMAgent.msi to be installed silently, which is what is running after mmasetup-i386.exe is extracted.  You can extract the setup file with `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Temp\MMASetup-i386.exe" -ArgumentList "/Q /T:c:\temp\working /C" -wait`, and then run another start-process to start momagent.msi (or the setup.exe) with the appropriate parameters.  You need to figure out how to install this silently WITHOUT Powershell first...

Comment: ..., and then you can write a Powershell script to run the appropriate commands.

Comment: I am already following the same document you mentioned above.

Comment: Right-click on the file, select Properties, and click the Unblock button near the bottom.

Comment: How would you, with this approach, set the workspace ID and workspace key, which is normally entered interactively in the setup wizard?

Comment: @FlorianWinter See http://www.operationsmanagementsuite.org/2016/02/08/install-the-oms-agent-using-the-command-line/